# Bootstrap Modal - Move backdrop outside of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've integrated [this](http://villeristi.github.io/bootstrapModalExtended/) small plug in that adds animate.css animations to Bootstrap Modals. However, when the modal animates in, the backdrop animates in also as depicted in the image.

In the plugin demo, the backdrop appears *outside* of the modal.

**How can I replicate this behavior?**

[image]

My JS & HTML is the same as the example from what I can see.

```
$('body').append(template(options));
el = $("#"+options.id);

el.modal({
    animateIn: 'fadeInDown',
    animateOut: 'fadeOutLeft'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal {{#if icon}}with-icon{{/if}}" id="{{id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="{{id}}Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog {{size}}">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <i class="icons8-{{icon}} icon"></i>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            {{{content}}}
            </div>
            {{#if buttons}}
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{#each buttons}}
                <button type="button" class="btn {{class}}" data-dismiss="modal">{{label}}</button>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? Where are you defining `el`?

Comment: I edited the answer with my JS and HTML. It's a handlebars compiled template.